# YA vampire novel with ties to the Dracula mythos. Renfield's name was flipped around to Dleifner

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, vampire, dracula

I think the book took place in a library? Maybe. I definitely remember Renfield's name being flipped around. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[Prison of Vampires](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1389983.Prisoner_of_Vampires)* by Nancy Garden.

> While writing a term paper on vampires, twelve-year-old Alexander
>   finds himself falling under the spell of Dracula and his family of
>   vampires who are operating a funeral parlor in Massachusetts.

On of the main characters is a [Mr. Dleifner](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8srrAAAAMAAJ&q=Dleifner&source=gbs_word_cloud_r&cad=6)

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks for solving a mystery that's plagued me for years!

Comment: @SplittingAdam - http://s1.favim.com/orig/2/austin-powers-mike-myers-yeah-baby-Favim.com-151109.jpg